# How to insert second array value into first array with php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have multidimensional array given from thirth party supplier with detail as bellow.

```
$data = array ( 
    "studentData" => array (
        array(
            "university" => array(
                "name" => "Tes Name",
                "address" => "Street name",
                "province" => "Province name",
            ),
            "college" => array(
                "name" => "IT"
            ),
            "examDate" => "2019-01-20",
            "lesson" => 
            array(
                "lessonId" => 
                array(
                    "lessonIdNumber" => "40"
                )
            ),
            "countStudent" => "2",
            "examResult" =>
            array(
                array(
                    "studentGender" => "Male",
                    "studentName" => 
                    array(
                        array(
                            "name" => "George",
                            "result" => "98"
                        ),
                        array(
                            "name" => "Leonard",
                            "result" => "84"
                        ),
                    ),
                )
            )
        ),

        array(
            "university" => array(
                "name" => "Tes Name",
                "address" => "Street name",
                "province" => "Province name",
            ),
            "college" => array(
                "name" => "IT"
            ),
            "examDate" => "2019-01-20",
            "lesson" => 
            array(
                "lessonId" => 
                array(
                    "lessonIdNumber" => "41"
                )
            ),
            "countStudent" => "1",
            "examResult" =>
                array(
                    "studentGender" => "Female",
                    "examDate" => "2019-01-20",
                    "lessonId" => array(
                        "lessonIdNumber" => "40"
                    ),
                    "countStudent" => "1",
                    "studentName" => 
                    array(
                        array(
                            "name" => "Anita",
                            "result" => "71"
                        )
                    ),
                )
        ),

        array(
            "university" => array(
                "name" => "Tes Name",
                "address" => "Street name",
                "province" => "Province name",
            ),
            "college" => array(
                "name" => "Design Graphics"
            ),
            "examDate" => "2019-01-20",
            "lesson" => 
            array(
                "lessonId" => 
                array(
                    "lessonIdNumber" => "42"
                )
            ),
            "countStudent" => "3",
            "examResult" =>
            array(
                array(
                    "studentGender" => "Male",
                    "studentName" => 
                    array(
                        array(
                            "name" => "Edward",
                            "result" => "83"
                        ),
                        array(
                            "name" => "William",
                            "result" => "86"
                        ),
                        array(
                            "name" => "Oliver",
                            "result" => "77"
                        ),
                    ),
                )
            )
        ),

        array(
            "university" => array(
                "name" => "Tes Name",
                "address" => "Street name",
                "province" => "Province name",
            ),
            "college" => array(
                "name" => "Design Graphics"
            ),
            "examDate" => "2019-01-20",
            "lesson" => 
            array(
                "lessonId" => 
                array(
                    "lessonIdNumber" => "42"
                )
            ),
            "countStudent" => "2",
            "examResult" =>
                array(
                    array(
                        "studentGender" => "Female",
                        "studentName" => 
                        array(
                            array(
                                "name" => "Isabel",
                                "result" => "77"
                            ),
                            array(
                                "name" => "Dorothi",
                                "result" => "86"
                            )
                        ),
                    ),
                )
        ),
    ),
    "lessonData" => array (
        array(
            "lessonId" => array(
                "lessonIdNumber" => "40"
            ),
            "sessionName" => "PHP and Array",
            "teacherData" => array(
                "teacherName" => "Teacher Name One",
                "teacherId" => "229910",
            ),
        ),
        array(
            "lessonId" => array(
                "lessonIdNumber" => "41"
            ),
            "sessionName" => "Photoshop",
            "teacherData" => array(
                "teacherName" => "Teacher Name Two",
                "teacherId" => "981881",
            ),
        ),
        array(
            "lessonId" => array(
                "lessonIdNumber" => "42"
            ),
            "sessionName" => "Coreldraw",
            "teacherData" => array(
                "teacherName" => "Teacher Name Three",
                "teacherId" => "327718",
            ),
        )
    ),
);
```

Data output : https://3v4l.org/uUGsB

I have to modify result from above array base on every "lessonIdNumber" from "lessonData" tag with scenario : move value of [sessionName] and [teacherData] from [lessonData] into bellow each [lesson] in [studentData] array base on each [lessonIdNumber].

```
Array
(
    [studentData] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [university] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Tes Name
                            [address] => Street name
                            [province] => Province name
                        )
```

`[college] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => IT
                    )

                [examDate] => 2019-01-20
                [lesson] => Array
                    (
                        [lessonId] => Array
                            (
                                [lessonIdNumber] => 40
                            )

                    )

                [sessionName] => PHP and Array
                [teacherData] => Array
                    (
                        [teacherName] => Teacher Name One
                        [teacherId] => 229910
                    )

                [countStudent] => 2
                [examResult] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [studentGender] => Male
                                [studentName] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => George
                                                [result] => 98
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => Leonard
                                                [result] => 84
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [university] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Tes Name
                        [address] => Street name
                        [province] => Province name
                    )

                [college] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => IT
                    )

                [examDate] => 2019-01-20
                [lesson] => Array
                    (
                        [lessonId] => Array
                            (
                                [lessonIdNumber] => 41
                            )

                    )

                [sessionName] => Photoshop
                [teacherData] => Array
                    (
                        [teacherName] => Teacher Name Two
                        [teacherId] => 981881
                    )

                [countStudent] => 1
                [examResult] => Array
                    (
                        [studentGender] => Female
                        [examDate] => 2019-01-20
                        [lessonId] => Array
                            (
                                [lessonIdNumber] => 40
                            )

                        [countStudent] => 1
                        [studentName] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => Anita
                                        [result] => 71
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [university] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Tes Name
                        [address] => Street name
                        [province] => Province name
                    )

                [college] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Design Graphics
                    )

                [examDate] => 2019-01-20
                [lesson] => Array
                    (
                        [lessonId] => Array
                            (
                                [lessonIdNumber] => 42
                            )

                    )

                [sessionName] => Coreldraw
                [teacherData] => Array
                    (
                        [teacherName] => Teacher Name Three
                        [teacherId] => 327718
                    )

                [countStudent] => 3
                [examResult] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [studentGender] => Male
                                [studentName] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => Edward
                                                [result] => 83
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => William
                                                [result] => 86
                                            )

                                        [2] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => Oliver
                                                [result] => 77
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [university] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Tes Name
                        [address] => Street name
                        [province] => Province name
                    )

                [college] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Design Graphics
                    )

                [examDate] => 2019-01-20
                [lesson] => Array
                    (
                        [lessonId] => Array
                            (
                                [lessonIdNumber] => 42
                            )

                    )

                [sessionName] => Coreldraw
                [teacherData] => Array
                    (
                        [teacherName] => Teacher Name Three
                        [teacherId] => 327718
                    )

                [countStudent] => 2
                [examResult] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [studentGender] => Female
                                [studentName] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => Isabel
                                                [result] => 77
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => Dorothi
                                                [result] => 86
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )`

)

Result array : https://3v4l.org/lVFlF

I hope my question is clear and get solution. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it with initially mapping the lesson number to lesson data. Let's try like this way,

```
$student = $data['studentData'];
$lesson = $data['lessonData'];
$expected = [];

# mapping the lession id to lession data e.g 40=>[sessionName=>'Coreldraw','teacherData'=>[array]]
foreach($lesson as $key=>$value){
    $mapped[$value['lessonId']['lessonIdNumber']] = ['sessionName'=>$value['sessionName'],'teacherData'=>$value['teacherData']];
}

foreach($student as $k=>$v){
    $lesson_id = $v['lesson']['lessonId']['lessonIdNumber'];
    if(array_key_exists($lesson_id, $mapped)){
        $expected['studentData'][$k] = array_merge($student[$k], $mapped[$lesson_id]);
    }
}

print_r($expected);
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/9JW3J

Answer (score 1):

This does what you request...

```
$lessonData  = $data['lessonData'];
$studentData = $data['studentData'];

$lessons = array();

foreach ($lessonData as $lessonDat)
{
    $lessons[$lessonDat['lessonId']['lessonIdNumber']] = $lessonDat;
}

foreach ($studentData as $id=>$studentDat) {

    $studentData[$id]['sessionName'] = $lessons[$studentDat['lesson']['lessonId']['lessonIdNumber']]['sessionName'];
    $studentData[$id]['teacherData'] = $lessons[$studentDat['lesson']['lessonId']['lessonIdNumber']]['teacherData'];
}

unset($data['lessonData']);
```

I certainly do hope this is for work and not a coding assignment.  It's a pretty challenging task for a novice programmer but sounds like an awesome school assignment.

If so, I'd recommend you just use this to check your work, otherwise I hope it is of help.  Best of luck!

Comment: I apologize for this issue. Thank you for your assistance.